# Good introduction to estimating stochastic diffusion processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, econometrics, parameter-estimation, mle

So, in an advanced Econometrics course, the current topic relates to estimating transition densities and diffusion processes by MLE, such as this [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiffusionRgqd/vignettes/DiffusionRgqd_Paper.pdf) doc describes, for ex., and I have to admit to myself that I am starting to get lost.

What book(s) would you recommend for someone that has no background in Real/Complex analysis, yet still possesses a decent understanding of stochastic calc. and good background in fundamental econometrics? I am asking this because I feel most of the concepts are intuitive (if still the tiniest bit complex) once someone finally explains them to me, but actually following math texts/papers is difficult without a pure math background.

Any other quants that have experienced this can give me reading advice?

Comment: I found the papers of Ait Sahalia helpful in understanding estimation of diffusion processes. (I found them sophisticated but understandable). One of them is referenced in the document you linked.

Comment: Those articles do seem well-written indeed, despite being complex as you say.